# Disable "React DevTools is too old" warning

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

How do you disable/hide the React DevTools console warning in React 16:

`Warning: The installed version of React DevTools is too old and will not work with the current version of React. Please update React DevTools.`

Answer (score 1):

Put this code somewhere in the global scope:

```
__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ = {
  supportsFiber: true,
  inject: function() {},
  onCommitFiberRoot: function() {},
  onCommitFiberUnmount: function() {},
};
```